# Could someone point me in the right direction for this complex analysis equation?

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization, complex-numbers

I'm supposed to show that the maximum value of $|z^2+1|$ on the unit disk $|z|\leq1$ is 2.  My teacher's hint was "triangle inequality". I've been racking my brain how to tie the triangle inequality into this.  Any hints (vague hints are good, I want to learn from this) are welcome!

Thanks!

I have one other, very similar question.

Find the maximum value of |z^n+a| on the unit disk. What I have is:

$$|z^n+a|\leq |z^n|+|a| = |z|^n + |a|$$.

The unit disk is $|z|\leq 1$, so, raising each side to $n$ then adding $|a|$ gives us:

$$|z|^n +|a|\leq 1+|a|.$$

Hence,
$$|z^n+a|\leq 1 + |a|.$$

Thus, $|z^n+a|$ has a maximum value on $|z|\leq1$ of $1+|a|$.

Does that look believable?

Comment: You can use the triangle inequality on the expression $|z^2+1|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

The triangle inequality states that $|a+b| \le |a| + |b|$.  Apply this the the expression $|z^2+1|$, and consider the values $|z|$ takes on.  This will give you an upper bound to $|z^2+1|$, so you still have to show that $|z^2+1|$ actually achieves this upper bound, for example by finding a $z$ so that equality holds.

**Edit:**

To address the added question, we only need to show that equality can hold in the expression

$$|z^n+a| \le 1+|a|$$

To do so, we observe that we can take $z$ with $|z| = 1$ such that $\arg (z^n) = \arg a$.  The desired equality then follows by interpreting the expression $|z^n + a|$ geometrically.

Comment: I added an edit to the question, if you want to look at it.

Comment: @Lerbib I've updated my answer.